# Inheritance clarification in bitbake

Tags: yocto, bitbake

In bitbake, are inheritances transferable between include files when they are added with require keyword? Or do we need to reuse inherit keyword over and over again in each of the include files? I'm using bitbake to built images with Yocto.

**exampleA.inc file**

```
inherit exampleC
```

**exampleB.inc file**

```
require exampleA.inc
```

In that case, if I want exampleB.inc to be inherited from exampleC as well, do I need to specify it in this file?

Assume that the exampleC is a bbclass file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Request for clarification on Yocto inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288801/request-for-clarification-on-yocto-inheritance)

Comment: Thanks for your response but this answer does not clarify the inheritance relations between files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: one inherit statement is enough.

`require` and `include` just insert the content of the specified file at the current position in the recipe. This results in the same outcome, as if you had written the whole content of your `.inc` file into the recipe. Multiple layers of `include` / `require` should not change that. This means, that not the `.inc` file inherits from `exanpleC`, but rather the recipe, which requires said `.inc` file.

I also ran some quick tests to confirm the theory, and it all seems to work.

Do not be deterred by the BitBake documentation stating:

> [...] you can use the `inherit` directive to inherit the functionality of a class (.bbclass). BitBake only supports this directive when used within recipe and class files (i.e. .bb and .bbclass).

This does not mean, that it does not work in `.inc` files, but rather that it will not work for configuration files.